# AWS Neptune io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

So we're using apache tinkerpop and java client to connect to Neptune instance. Most of the queries are working fine. But submitting a larger query, it throws an exception.

`ERROR o.a.t.g.d.Handler$GremlinResponseHandler - Could not process the response
io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Max frame length of 65536 has been exceeded`

And used the following code to connect to the neptune.

```
Cluster.Builder builder = Cluster.build();
builder.addContactPoints(contactPoints);
builder.port(port);
builder.enableSsl(true);
cluster = builder.create();
return EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster));
```

And I get to know that changing .maxRequestLength will solve this. But unable to find out where to set this in neptune server config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the help from AWS support. 
Setting the maxContentLength in the java client solved the issue.

```
builder.maxContentLength(1024000);
```

And as of now, it is not possible to change this configuration in the Neptune server side. And this value can be increased upto 1GB.